# Pandas difficult to add new column with condition?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I was trying to do multiple group and also adding count to new column.

My input file

```
OrderDate   Region  Rep Item    Units   Unit Cost   Total
----------------------------------------------------------
1/6/18      East    Jones   Pencil  95   1.99    189.05 
1/23/18     Central Kivell  Binder  50   19.99   999.50 
2/9/18      Central Jardine Pencil  36   4.99    179.64 
2/26/18     Central Gill    Pen 27   19.99   539.73 
3/15/18     West    Sorvino Pencil  56   2.99    167.44 
4/1/18      East    Jones   Binder  60   4.99    299.40 
4/18/18     Central Andrews Pencil  75   1.99    149.25 
4/18/18     West    Jones   Pencil  75   1.99    149.25
```

I am trying to do like

```
Region Rep Count same/diff
-------------------------------
east jones  2    2-same
     jones
central Kivell  4 >3 differnce
        Jardine
        Gill    
        Andrews 
West  Sorvino 2   2-different
West  jones1
```

My code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name = 'SalesOrders', index_col=0)
df3 = (df1.groupby('Region')['Rep'].value_counts())

print(df3)
```

Please help me to do this. Thanks
In rep column, based on Region i have done group by to know Rep values. if Rep member are same then 2 same people, consider central region has 4 different people working so it i greater than 3 .

Comment: What does column `same/diff` mean? What you want to do with the data??

Comment: Two same values in REP column and its vice versa

Comment: then , what does `4 >3 differnce` mean?

Comment: if more than 3 values in which is same or different ..it has to be greater than 3

Comment: Cannot understand...

Comment: In rep column, based on Region i have done group by to know Rep values. if Rep member are same then 2 same people, consider central region has 4 different people working so more than 3